# domain.tld/sitemap.xml displays home page instead of sitemap

Tags: xml, .htaccess, sitemap

Today I tried several times to upload sitemap to my website.
But when I'm trying to access site map on browser by visiting 'mydomain.com/sitemap.xml' is appears the homepage.

Please help me.

**Edited Root site's htaccess**

(above mentioned site is a site which in sub folder accessing using addon domain)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_xmap&id=2&view=xml
# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.  (php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: Please share your `.htaccess` file. We cannot accurately guess what is causing the problem without it. First guess would be that you have a `RewriteRule` interfering here.

Comment: There is no htaccess script for this folder (domain).

Comment: I am using above site as a addon domain. root site has a htaccess

Comment: Does `/sitemap.xml` *redirect* to `mydomain.com/`, or does it show the home page *without* redirecting?

Comment: Main post edited with root site's htaccess

Comment: It shows the home page without redirecting

Comment: Well, as you can guess, your main domain won't impact the addon domain. As such, I can't figure out what is going on there. Anything else in your addon domain directory?

Comment: So what home page is appearing?

Comment: my addon domain's home page.
In brief, when I trying to connect with domain.com/sitemap.xml, domain.com/index.php appears without redirecting

Comment: The only way that can happen is if a `RewriteRule` is rewriting the request. As you say there is no `.htaccess` file for the addon domain, I can't imagine what is causing this. It could be a hosting configuration issue - you may want to contact your host. Alternatively, and if you have access to folders above your public folder (that is, thee root domain folder), then point your addon domain to a new folder in there.